# JAXB Overwriting package-info.java: What should be "namespace"?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We're using xjc to generate JAXB Java classes for XML generation. Everything works fine except we tried to adjust the generated namespace prefixes [as described here](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2011/03/jaxb-marshalling-with-custom-namespace.html). We're stuck with "solution 2", adjusting package-info.java, due to the JAXB version we're using.

The structure we have is several imports deep: root namespace imports other namespace, which in turn imports yet a third one.

**MCVE xsds**

root.xsd (imports other.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="root" xmlns:other="other" targetNamespace="root" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="other" schemaLocation="other.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="rootElem">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="rootElem1"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="rootElem1" nillable="false">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="data">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice>
                            <xs:element ref="other:otherElem"/>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

other.xsd (imports third.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:other="other" xmlns:third="third" targetNamespace="other" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
<xsd:import namespace="third" schemaLocation="third.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="otherElem">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="third:thirdElem" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

third.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:third="third" targetNamespace="third" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="thirdElem">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="thirdData" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

With this

**Simple test case**

```
@Test
public void test() throws JAXBException
{
    Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance("test.jaxb.generated").createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.example.com/schema.xsd");

    RootElem root = new RootElem();
    RootElem1 root1 = new RootElem1();
    Data d = new Data();
    OtherElem other = new OtherElem();
    ThirdElem thirdElem = new ThirdElem();
    thirdElem.setThirdData("third");
    other.setThirdElem(thirdElem);
    d.setOtherElem(other);
    root1.setData(d);
    root.setRootElem1(root1);

    Path path = Paths.get("target", "outfile.xml");

    Result result = new StreamResult(path.toFile());
    marshaller.marshal(root, result);
}
```

this results in this

**Generated XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:rootElem xmlns:ns2="other" xmlns:ns3="third" xmlns:ns4="root" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema.xsd">
    <ns4:rootElem1>
        <data>
            <ns2:otherElem>
                <ns3:thirdElem>
                    <ns3:thirdData>third</ns3:thirdData>
                </ns3:thirdElem>
            </ns2:otherElem>
        </data>
    </ns4:rootElem1>
</ns4:rootElem>
```

and everything is fine (except `data` which doesn't have any namespace associated, I'm assuming because that's an inner type).

Now this is partly the question: here's the

**generated package-info.java**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "other", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package test.jaxb.generated;
```

Why is the `namespace` given referring to `other`? My root namespace is `root`. (`root.xsd` is the only file we're giving our Maven `jaxb2-maven-plugin`; we can include the others, it makes no difference).

**Wrong replacement package-info.java**

If we overwrite the generated one with this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "root",
        xmlns = {
                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "t", namespaceURI = "third"),
                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "o", namespaceURI = "other"),
                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "r", namespaceURI = "root")
        },
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package test.jaxb.generated;
```

which we initially did because we assumed we have to give the root namespace here - this is the

**Wrong Generated XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<r:rootElem xmlns:t="third" xmlns:o="other" xmlns:r="root" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema.xsd">
    <r:rootElem1>
        <data>
            <r:otherElem>
                <t:thirdElem>
                    <t:thirdData>third</t:thirdData>
                </t:thirdElem>
            </r:otherElem>
        </data>
    </r:rootElem1>
</r:rootElem>
```

Now the namespaces are pretty, but wrong! `otherElem` belongs to `o`, not `r`.

Changing the namespace in the overwriting file back to `other` fixes the error, but again:

the question is why is the required namespace `other` here? Just as confusing is the fact that the `third` imported layer is correct either way.

The problem is fixed, but we'd like to understand the concept. What are we missing?

EDIT:

For completeness' sake, here's the `build` section of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <!-- run xjc -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-generate_classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>test.jaxb.generated</packageName>
                        <schemaFiles>
                            root.xsd
                        </schemaFiles>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemata</schemaDirectory>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/jaxb/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- overwrite created package-info.java -->
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/jaxb/test/jaxb/generated</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings</directory>
                                <include>package-info.java</include>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How do you configure `test.jaxb.generated` as the target package?

Comment: @lexicore in the pom.xml. I added it to the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you generate all your classes in one package (configured using the `packageName` of the Maven plugin.

Do not do this.

JAXB is somewhat based on the concept of package-namespace correspondence. There should be one package per namespace you use. While it is technically possible to do it otherwise, you'll be facing one problem after another. So it is better to follow this concept and use or generate one package per namespace. You can still configure target packages - but using the binding files instead of plugin configuration elements.

Comment: But how do I configure it to only generate the one package I need? The `root.xsd` given in the `pom.xml` already sucks in the imported schemas and generates code from them. I did try generating the imported ones separately, but that just results in code that doesn't get used (because the code generated by `root.xsd` only uses the classes generated it its own `xjc` run). And if I manage to limit the packages - how will the `root` classes know the ones they need to import?

Comment: @daniu Not sure what your problem is. You should generate three packages here, not one. That `root.xsd` imports other schemas does not matter. You can customize target package per schema using bindings. I really don't see the problem.

Comment: So I need to create a `bindings.xjb` which assigns each namespace to a package? Do I also need to adjust the `pom.xml`? Because I don't know how I would split it to be able to configure separate target packages there.

Comment: @daniu If you want to specify packages for namespaces, yes, the recommended way is to use `bindings.xjb`. In the plugin just remove `packageName` config element (I guess so). You don't need to configure separate packages in `pom.xml` (you can't), you do it in `bindings.xjb`.

Comment: @daniu Here's an [example](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/gml/3.1.1/src/main/resources/gml-v_3_1_1.xjb). Look for `jaxb:schemaBindings` with `jaxb:package`, the rest is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay so that works... thanks. A more robust solution to the problem I guess.. although I still don't know why it works with `other` as `namespace` in the overwriting `package-info.java`.

Comment: @daniu With some analysis one can find this out. But it's just not worth it, in my opinion.